# How to limit build task only to VSTS not TFS

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-devops-rest-api

I have a VSTS extension with two build tasks, one build task should be available for both VSTS and TFS, the other one only for TFS. Is it possible to configure this for each build task via extension manifest?

Comment: I don;t think this is possible, why do you need 2 tasks? What is special about the task that it needs to be different, I suspect you'd be able to detect TFS/VSTS in your implementation and would be able to provide a single task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the following workaround to display message and discontinue the build in TFS.

```
var collectionUrl = process.env["SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI"];
var regExpression = new RegExp("^((https?)\:\/\/)(([a-z0-9])+\.)*(visualstudio\.com)");
if(regExpression.test(collectionUrl))
{
    //VSTS Detected
}
else
{
   //Display message task not compatible with TFS
   //Fail the build
}
```

Comment: I guess now all builds fail in Azure DevOps ;)

Comment: @matthid It will just fail for new projects, Microsoft announced that they will keep old domain as it is

Comment: @Lalindu indeed, but afaik there is a switch in the admin settings to use the new domain. I guess best is to update the code. In fact I had similar code in an extension which had to be fixed... The comment should just be a reminder for people seeing this.

Answer (score 0):

Make the [extension manifest](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/manifest) indicates that the extension is available only for Team Services (`targets = Microsoft.Visualstudio.Services.Cloud`).

Comment: Do you mean to create two extensions, one with the `targets` set to MS.VS.Sevices.Cloud containing the build task only for VSTS, and another extension with `targets` set to MS.VS.Services containing the other build task available for both TFS and VSTS?

Comment: @Cece: This limits the extension only to VSTS, my requirement is to limit one build task to VSTS while other one should support both VSTS and TFS. Thanks.

Comment: @LucaCappa, Yes, that's what I mean. Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: @Bandara, Sorry for confusion. LucaCappa has explained what I mean. You may need to create two extensions.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any way to achieve this via extension manifest file. A good workaround is just as jessehouwing mentioned: Combine the two build tasks into one, provide an option in build setting to let user select or detect the build environment when running the build task. If TFS is selected or detected, run the code in the two build tasks, otherwise just run the code in the first build task.