# How to get Version of TFS in Build Extension

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I need to check version of client's TFS server using my TFS extension.My aim is to identify whether it is TFS 2015.2 (or later version) or TFS 2017. Is this feasible (inbuilt/ out of the box method available) or  Is there any workaround available to achieve this. Please help.

As per below post it is possible to differentiate VSTS from TFS. But I need one step forward to get specific version.
[How to limit build task only to VSTS not TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41499650/how-to-limit-build-task-only-to-vsts-not-tfs?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no related rest API will directly return TFS version number.

However as a workaround you could start from one place **[*API-version*](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/rest/basics#supported-versions)**. For example, the **3.0 API** set was introduced with **Team Foundation Server 2017**. It's not support on TFS 2015.